# Is it possible to programmatically configure NLog when used with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, nlog

I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection in my Project and want to use Microsoft.Extension.Logging, with NLog as the actual Logging Framework.

Since I want to be able to decide the Logging Configuration on Startup programmatically (to get around pathing issues) i'm doing something like this:

```
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
var dirPath = Path.Combine(publicStorage, "Test");
var logFileTarget = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget()
{
    CreateDirs = true,
    FileName = Path.Combine(dirPath, "test.log"),
    FileNameKind = NLog.Targets.FilePathKind.Absolute,
    Layout = "${date}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message} ${exception}|${logger}|${all-event-properties}",
    Name = "FileLog",
};

//Add Logging Targets
config.AddTarget(logFileTarget);

//Add Rules
config.AddRuleForAllLevels(logFileTarget, "*", false);

LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

But this does not configure those Loggers returned by `ServiceProvider.GetService<ILogger<T>>`.
If I however use `LogManager.GetLogger("TestLogger")` The Logging is configured as would be expected.

`LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();` doesn't solve the Problem as well and my search came up empty

Edit

The DI Setup looks like this:

```
return new ServiceCollection()
    // Configure Logging Provider
    .AddLogging(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddDebug();
        //Add NLog
        builder.AddNLog(new NLogProviderOptions()
        {
            CaptureMessageTemplates = true,
            CaptureMessageProperties = true,
        });
    })
... // Registering additional dependencies
.BuildServiceProvider();
```

> Using `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger` gives the same "incorrect behaviour" as seen with the Loggers returned by serviceProvider. Since 
>   the rule is setup with `"*"` I would have expected that all loggers including those using class names are caught by this rule

This last sentence is incorrect it is actually working, but the non-appearance of ILogger by di messages still exists

Comment: Please add your configuration for DI.

Comment: Since I got myself out of concept already I have expanded the information in my question I hope this is more helpful and I will take a few minutes pause now

Comment: Remember the missing `builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);` see also wiki: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application#32-setup-the-dependency-injector-di-container

Comment: Thanks that's it. Can you post that as an Answer so I can accept it as the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the missing:

```
builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
```

See also wiki: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application#32-setup-the-dependency-injector-di-container

Comment: This still works in ASP.NET Core 5, however, make sure you remove the Default log level in your appsettings.json file(s) as noted here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-5#4-configure-appsettingsjson